# How to pass values from one custom cell to another view controller by using global variables for iMessage?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, imessage-extension

I'm trying to develop an iMessage App and i'm not sure how to pass values from a custom cell to another view controller. I need to make sure that once the button is pressed the value from the cell is copied to the text sending space. Please help me out! Im stuck here :

[This is the iMessage Code and instead of "hello world" it needs to put the label text from the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFTJr.png)

```
        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
        layout.caption = "Hello World"

        let message = MSMessage()
        message.layout = layout

        self.activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: nil)
```

[The part which has the details on the cell in a different view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpxxA.png)

```
        func configureWithContactEntry(_ contact: ContactEntry) {
        contactNameLabel.text = contact.name
        contactEmailLabel.text = contact.email ?? ""
        contactPhoneLabel.text = contact.phone ?? ""


        return cell
```

[This is the CellForRow code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94hjR.png)

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
    "ContactTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactTableViewCell
    let entry = filteredContacts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.configureWithContactEntry(entry)
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
```

Would be great if anybody could help me out!

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code, not links to pictures of the code.

Comment: @pbasdf- yeah sure will do that! Just a moment!

Comment: Can you post the code when you make your transition to another view controller ?

Comment: Maybe it's a great case to use delegation pattern, do you know that ?

Comment: @Arrabidas92 No i dont know how the delegation pattern works...im kind of new to this :/

Comment: Here is a link explaining the delegation pattern : https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your cell data to other controller in your imessage extension in this way. check your cell selected override function its look like

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    print("cell selected at row \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Get model data on the base of indexPath from your model object, in your case you should get from this function.

```
let entry = filteredContacts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
let name = entry.name
```

After that create Msession object and fill data in it from your entry object.

```
let session = MSSession()
        let message = MSMessage(session: session)
        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
        layout.caption = name


        message.layout = layout

        //save the message in the current conversation context

        self.savedConversation?.insert(message,
                                       completionHandler: { (err) in

                                        print("ERROR \(err.debugDescription)")
        })
```

Also if you want to append image in message then do it this way.

```
        layout.image = UIImage(named:"image.png")!
```

Comment: Where should this go ??                                                                                let entry = filteredContacts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
let name = entry.name   @Shauket Sheik

Comment: in this overrided method didSelectRowAtIndexPath , after that you can use this in layout